# ¿Como hago para llamar a otro programa al terminar la ejecucion de uno en C?

Tags: c, linux

El problema es el siguiente:

Al llamar la funcion `system()` esta espera recibir el nombre de un programa con la extension .exe (en caso de windows) pero yo al intentarlo en linux no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, ya que .exe no se usa y al probar distintas variantes me sale el mensaje

```
"nombredelprograma" not found.
```

Ambos programas ya fueron ejecutados por lo cual ya debería generarse el ejecutable para llamarlo. Anteriormente tenia la variable

```
int codigo 
codigo = system(nombredelprograma)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `system` ejecuta comandos. Así que si lo escribís como `./programa` capaz que funcione.

Comment: Al editar tu pregunta observé que intentaste publicar una imagen de tu código fuente. Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y publica el código como texto, [no como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La función [`system()`](https://linuxhint.com/system-function-in-c-language/) ejecuta comandos.

Es decir, pasa la cadena que recibe, como tal, al interprete de comandos del sistema, que es el que la ejecuta.

Esto significa que debes pasar el comando de la misma manera que lo escribirías en el *prompt* del sistema. En el caso de Linux, si quieres ejecutar un comando externo, es decir, un programa, debes enviar la ruta a dicho programa.

Esta ruta puede ser una ruta relativa o una ruta absoluta.

Si el programa está en el directorio actual, no estás eximido de la regla, por lo que debes pasar o bien la ruta completa el directorio actual, o la ruta relativa al directorio actual, usando la *pseudo carpeta* `.`, por ejemplo:

```
system("./miPrograma");
```

O, concretamente en tu caso:

```
system("./pedirDni");
```

Y no solo

```
system("pedirDni");
```

Pues, en ese caso, el interprete de comandos buscará un comando interno con dicho nombre y responderá que no se encuentra.

De hecho, puedes comprobar que, en tu caso, es el interprete "sh" el que está emitiendo el error, pues se identifica en el mensaje del mismo:

```
sh: 1: pedirDni: not found
```

Por otro lado, también puedes ejecutar comandos internos, por ejemplo:

```
system("ls -h");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`system`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) pasa el comando a la shell (**sh**) para que lo ejecute. Así que estás sujeto a sus reglas para ejecutar comandos.

En pocas palabras, si escribes solamente el nombre del programa lo va a buscar en las carpetas del PATH. Lo más probable es que no esté en ninguna y no lo encuentre o termine ejecutando otro programa con el mismo nombre.

Es necesario agregar `./` para ejecutar un programa que esté en el directorio actual. También puedes utilizar la ruta completa al programa.

Puedes consultar la [documentación](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html) para más información.