# ¿Por que cuando ejecuto un programa c++ en gitbash me salen errores?

Tags: c++, git-bash

Cuando ejecuto un programa `c++` en `Powershell` funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo hago en `gitbash` me salen errores.

A continuación listo los comandos que he utilizado y los correspondientes errores que me salen:

```
> a.exe
command not found

> ./a.exe
segmentation fault

> .\a.exe
command not found (este es el que utilizo en powershell)
```

Comment: De los tres comandos el único correcto es bash es `./a.exe`.

Comment: gracias, pero entonces ¿A qué se puede deber el segfault?

Comment: Deberías añadir algunas trazas para saber en qué punto aparece el error. ¿Llega a iniciar la ejecución? ¿Tiene que ver con el lincado de alguna dll?

Comment: Yo simplemente escribo g++ main.cpp, me crea el archivo a.exe y cuando lo ejecuto es que me sale el error

Comment: ¿Llega a iniciar la ejecución? Si escribes un `std::cout << "Hola mundo";` en la primera línea de tu función `main` ¿llega a ejecutarlo?

Comment: No.  Lo compila (aparentemente porque no da error y genera el ejecutable) pero no lo ejecuta, me dice segmentation fault

Comment: Igual digo una tontería y me meto en un campo que no domino, pero a mi me suena que compilas para un sistema y ejecutas en otro distinto. Debes compilar para el destino.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/594262/169744) explico por qué el primer y tercer comando no funcionan. **Gitbash** al fin y al cabo es un terminal que emula **Bash**, por lo tanto es de esperar que funcione similarmente.

Comment: ¿Si compilas un programa con el compilador de Microsoft tienes el mismo problema al ejecutarlo con Gitbash?

Comment: Algo me dice que es probable que el problema sea otro pero igual me da un poco de curiosidad. ¿Me enseñarias una parte de tu codigo(Preferiblemente solo main?

Comment: //no creo que el problema sea el código porque en powershell se ejecuta perfectamente, pero me gusta más gitbash y por eso quiero poder ejecutarlo en gitbash pero me da segfault. De todos modos esto es una muestra de lo que estoy haciendo                                                                                                                                for (int i = 1; i<10; i++){
    cout<<"\nTabla del "<<i<<endl;
    for (int j = 1; j<11; j++){
        cout<<i<<" x "<<j<<" = "<<i*j<<endl;
    }

Comment: A caracas, tienes razon no es el codigo...

Comment: Consegui este problema parecido: [Application works in cmd, gives segfault in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769156/application-works-in-cmd-gives-segfault-in-git-bash)

Comment: Creo que ud ha dado con el problema. Ahora que lo pienso, tengo dos directorios mingw, uno es el que venía con gitbash y otro que venía en el paquete de gcc, este último lo tengo en c: , así que creo que ese puede ser el problema. Lo malo es que ahí el hombre solo dice que gitbash estaba cargando una librería desde un directorio equivocado pero no dice cómo hizo para que lo cargara desde el directorio correcto.

Comment: iiSimple no usar gitbash!!, je mentira creo que ... tambien tuve ese mismo problema al descargar gcc y mingw32 al mismo tiempo(Aqui me daba error de linkeado), al final elimine el path de uno(con el compilador tambien) en la ruta de entorno.

Comment: Recomiendo que coloques el código en la pregunta :D

Answer (score -4):

Los comandos en PowerShell y GitBash tienen diferencias porque el segundo es un entorno Unix en Windows. El problema es que `.\a.exe` ejecuta en la carpeta actual segun PowerShell pero en en GitBash debes usar la barra invertida `./a.exe` y el "Segmentation fault" te dice que el programa C++ tiene un error de acceso a la memoria.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero te sugerimos revisar [answer].